# Convert table to Byte array

Tags: .net, arrays, lua, luainterface, clrpackage

I'm trying to convert a Lua Table to a C# Byte array.  I was able to get a conversion to a Double array to work as follows:

```
> require 'CLRPackage'
> import "System"
> tbl = {11,22,33,44}
> dbl_arr = Double[4]
> dbl_arr:GetValue(0)
> dbl_arr:GetValue(1)
> for i=0,3 do Console.WriteLine(dbl_arr:GetValue(i)) end
0
0
0
0
> for i,v in ipairs(tbl) do dbl_arr:SetValue(v,i-1) end
> for i=0,3 do Console.WriteLine(dbl_arr:GetValue(i)) end
11
22
33
44
>
```

However if I change the `dbl_arr` to a `Byte` array (`dbl_arr = Byte[4]`), then I get the following error: `(error object is not a string)`

I've tried a bunch of different things with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I was able to get a bit more information from the error by doing this:

```
suc,err = pcall(function() byte_arr:SetValue(12,0) end)
```

Now `suc` is false and `err` returns the following message:

```
SetValue failed
System.ArgumentException: Cannot widen from source type to target type either
   because the source type is a not a primitive type or the conversion cannot
   be accomplished.
at System.Array.InternalSetValue(Void* target, Object value)
at System.Array.SetValue(Object value, Int32 index)
```

I've installed luaforwindows from [here](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/downloads/list). It's version 5.1.4-45.  I'm running Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3

**Update:**

This is the example code and where the error occurs

```
> require 'CLRPackage'
> import "System"
> tbl = {11,22,33,44}
> dbl_arr = Byte[4]
> for i,v in ipairs(tbl) do dbl_arr:SetValue(v,i-1) end <-- Error occurs here
```

Comment: Where does `dbl_arr` come from?

Comment: @Nicol - Its just a Double array that I created: `dbl_arr = Double[4]`

Comment: Fair enough. I meant where `Double[4]` comes from. Is it using some kind of metatable to create objects using []?

Comment: @Nicol, That's the [LuaInterface syntax](http://penlight.luaforge.net/packages/LuaInterface/#T5) to create a new array of `Double`s. The metatable method you describe is probably how it's done under the hood.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk3bwkb0.aspx): `Array.SetValue` throws an `ArgumentException` when "the current `Array` does not have exactly one dimension". So, there might be a bug in LuaInterface.

Comment: @superuser - I would expect the error in that case to be something like `Array was not a one-dimensional array`.  I'm still guessing it has to do with a type conversion happening somewhere, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @SwDevMan81, You're probably right. I would hook up the debugger if possible.

Comment: Where exactly is the error occurring? It would help if you could post the byte array version and where it's failing.

Comment: @Jon - I updated to include the exact code and where the problem occurs

Comment: I would [file a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/issues/list) with the LuaInterface team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue.  I'll post it here, although I'm still curious why the above doesn't work.

Here is the workaround.  I basically create a `MemoryStream` and use the `WriteByte` function to force the value to a Byte (since there is no overload of the function, it only accepts a byte).  Then I call `ToArray` to get the `byte[]` from the `MemoryStream`:

```
> require 'CLRPackage'
> import "System"
> tbl = {11,22,33,44}
> mem_stream = MemoryStream()
> for i,v in ipairs(tbl) do mem_stream:WriteByte(v) end
> byte_arr = mem_stream:ToArray()
> for i=0,byte_arr.Length-1 do Console.WriteLine(string.format("%d", byte_arr:GetValue(i))) end
11
22
33
44
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is that [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) does NOT have an overload that takes a `Byte` .

I don't know enough about Lua - in C# I would call [`GetValue(i).ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd12z8ts.aspx)  or [`Convert.ToString(GetValue(i), 16)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s62fh68.aspx) and give the result of that call to `Console.WriteLine`.

**EDIT - as per comment:**

Then you need to convert to Byte - in C# I would do something like `dbl_arr:SetValue((Byte)0,4)` or `dbl_arr:SetValue((Byte)v,4)` - I don't know how this is done Lua.

EDIT 2 - as per comment:
`double` is 8 bytes, `Single/float` is 4 Bytes.

Comment: Thats for the response, I should have mentioned the error occurs while running the for loop to try and `SetValue`.  It will print all 0's fine, but when I try and do something like `dbl_arr:SetValue(0,4)`, I get the `(error object is not a string)` message

Comment: Yeah, unfortunetly there isnt a way to cast.  I tried doing `Convert.ToByte(4)` and passing that in, but it still fails.  I have a feeling its storing the intermediate results as a Lua 'number', which then automatically converts it to a C# `Double`.  This is the only explanation I can come up with based on that error.

Comment: see the comment from @superuser above : that would be an explanation since the CLR makes a distinction between a vector (0-based 1 dimension) and a 1-dimensional Array.

Comment: Aren't doubles 8 bytes (64bit) each and singles 4 bytes (32bit) each.